# Probability Density And Mass Function

Tags: statistics

I have been trying to learn statistics from here and there. And I would say I am still struggling to understand the basic concepts or logic.

As per my knowledge, mass function basically gives the probability of an outcomes which are discrete in nature.Example : a flip of a coin.

Whereas, density function gives the probability of an outcomes which are continuous in nature. Example : Temperature in last 24 hours.

For any event, these distribution maps the normal distribution curve.

Please let me know if my understanding is correct and **what more do I need to learn to have solid understanding**.

Comment: "For any event, these distribution maps the normal distribution curve" What you mean by that is unclear (and probably wrong). Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the basic concepts. Maybe I can help clarify a few things.

**Discrete distributions.** The PMF (some books say PDF) assigns probabilities to
a finite or countable number of discrete points The binomial distributions are
examples.

In particular if $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n,\theta),$ then the formula $f(k) = P(X = k) = {n \choose k}\theta^k (1-\theta)^{n-k},$ assigns probabilities to the integers $k = 0, 1, \dots, n.$

A valid, PMF assigns probabilities $f(k) \ge 0$ such that $\sum_{k \in S} f(k) = 1,$ where the 'support' $S$ is the set of all values $k$ to which probabilities are assigned.

If you are asked to evaluate the probability of what appears to be an interval, then you need to focus on the points $k \in S$ that belong to that interval. 
For example, if $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(20, 1/2)$ and you are asked for
$Q = P(5 \le X \le 15),$ then you need to sum probabilities for the values of $k$ in $[5,15]$ in order to find $Q = \sum_{k = 5}^{15} {20 \choose k}(1/2)^n = 0.9882.$
In R statistical software a binomial PMF is `dbinom` so the computation below
does the work of evaluating eleven binomial coefficients:

```
sum(dbinom(5:15, 20, .5))
## 0.9881821
```

Some discrete distributions take countably many values. For example, if $Y$ has the distribution $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda)$ then the PMF is $f(k) = P(Y = k) = e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k/k!,$ for $k = 0, 1, \dots.$

The expected value $E(X)$ of a discrete random variable is defined as
$E(X) = \sum_{k \in S} kf(k).$ If $S$ is countable but not finite, then you
need to check that $\sum_{k in S} |k|f(k)$ converges; if not then $E(X)$ is not
defined for that distribution.

**Continuous random variables.** The density function $f(x)$ (also called the PDF) of a
continuous random variable $X$ taking values in $R$ must have

(i) $f(x) \ge 0,$ for all $x \in R$ and

(ii) $\int_R f(x)\,d(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\, dx = 1.$

(iii) Furthermore, probabilities of intervals are
defined by $P(a < X \le b) = \int_a^b f(x)\, dx.$

According to (iii) only intervals have probability. However, probabilities can be
assigned to unions and complements of intervals according to Kolmogorov Axioms.
A single point has probability $0:$ so $P(X = 0) = P(X = \sqrt{2}) = 0$ and
$P(a < X \le b) = P(a \le X \le b) = P(a < X < b).$ If you 'need' $P(X = 10)$
for a particular application, you need to consider that the 'point'  $\{X = 10\}$ may
be shorthand for the interval $\{9.5 < X \le 10.5\},$ which can have a non-zero probability.

Some continuous random variables have an interval subset $S$ of $R$ as support.
In that case $f(x) = 0$ for $x \notin S.$ A couple of frequent examples are
$S = (0, 1)$ and $S = (0, \infty).$

The expected value $E(X)$ of a continuous random variable with density function
$f(x)$ is defined as $E(X) = \int_S xf(x)\, dx,$ provided $\int_S |x|f(x)\, dx$ converges.

The cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a continuous random variable
is defined as $F(t) = P(X \le t) = \int_{-\infty}^t f(x)\,dx,$ for $t \in R.$ The CDF
of a continuous random variable $X$ must be everywhere continuous, but it may have
points where it is not differentiable. At points of differentiability,
$f(t) = dF(t)/dt.$ Then $P(a < X \le b) = F(b) - F(a).$

*Normal distributions.* You mentioned normal distributions as examples of continuous random variables.
That is correct, but they are only one kind of continuous random variable.

Furthermore, consider the standard normal random variable $Z$ with density function 
$\varphi(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-.5z^2},$ for $z \in R.$ This density function cannot be
integrated by the usual methods of calculus, and numerical integration must
be used to find, for example $P(0 < Z \le 1).$ There are printed tables of
the standard probabilities $P(0 < Z \le z)$ for various values of $z.$ Furthermore, software is available to do the required numerical integration.
For example, in R `pnorm` (without additional parameters)
is the standard normal CDF, so $P(0 < Z \le 1) = 0.3413447$ can be evaluated as follows.

```
pnorm(1) - pnorm(0)
## 0.3413447
```

*A simpler continuous distribution.* Let the random variable $X$ have the
distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(2,1)$ with density function $f(x) = 2x,$ for $0 <x < 1$ (and $0$ elsewhere). Then you can verify that $E(X) = 1/2,\,$ $P(0 < X < .5) = 1/4$ and that the CDF is $F(x) = x^2,$ for $0 < x < 1;$ also, $F(x) = 0,$ for 
$x < 0$ and $F(x) = 1,$ for $x > 1.$